# Signup not working - Server returns 404 Error Code

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, sdk, mongodb-stitch

**MongoDB Stitch: iOS SDK - Signup Issue:**

I tried this:

```
let stitchClient = StitchClient(appId: "<my-app-id>")
stitchClient.register(email: email, password: password).then({ () in

    print("Signed up here")
})
.catch({ (err) in

    print("Sign up fu**ed up: \(err)")
})
```

and always getting this:

> responseParsingFailed("Received no valid data from server").

When I hit the signup URL(https://stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/my-app-name/auth/providers/local-userpass/register/)

with these params ({"email": "what@mailinator.com", "password": "password"}) as part of the body,

the server returns:

> 404 page not found

Am I doing anything that's not expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine– this was unfortunately an issue on our end.

A maintenance release has been released to amend this issue. The version number is 2.0.4. Please update your `Podfile` accordingly and update the pod.