# mongodb stitch android email/pass register 404 error

Tags: android, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I am using MongoDb Stitch Android SDK to register a user with the email/password authentication system.

But getting a 404 error when calling the method register(name,pass) in the SDK.

**`Unexpected response code 404 for https://stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/<<app-name>>/auth/local-userpass/register`**

I have added valid URLs (for submission and password confirmation) in the stitch console when setting up an email provider.

I see a post with a similar issue for iOS SDK - which was fixed in an SDK update - [Signup not working - Server returns 404 Error Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959741/signup-not-working-server-returns-404-error-code)

I am using latest Android SDK 'org.mongodb:stitch:3.0.0'

Could somebody assist with this.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that has now been patched in the latest release, 3.0.2.

Please update your Gradle file accordingly to use `org.mongodb:stitch:3.0.2`.

Comment: Thanks - I upgraded but now i am getting a crash : :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_773e439/Offline;
                      at com.mongodb.stitch.android.StitchClientFactory.$jacocoInit(SourceFile)
                      at com.mongodb.stitch.android.StitchClientFactory.create(SourceFile)